# NodeJS not receiving data from PHP via cURL?

Tags: php, node.js, curl

1.) Trying to get NodeJS to get $content from PHP. I don't know what is wrong.

2.) Then trying to send the value back to PHP (simplification right now, but I will do something with the value before sending it back. Just trying to get the send/receive process working)

**PHP Code:**

```
$url = 'http://123.456.789:8080/panel/';
$content = json_encode("your data to be sent");

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($curl);
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);

echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $response . "' );</script>";
```

**NodeJS Code:**

```
router.post('/panel/', function(request, response){
    var myValue = request.body.data;
    console.log(myValue);
    response.send(myValue);
    response.end();
});
```

Comment: EXTRA: I tried file_get_content on PHP and it does work for router.get, so no issues with connection.

Comment: at the console in NodeJS it is shown the post data?

Comment: @JoseRojas No. It looks like router.post is not being called.

Comment: @JoseRojas but when I do `file_get_contents($url);` on `router.get('/panel/', function ...)` PHP was able to read that function. I don't know why there is a disconnect when PHP trys to send a value instead.

Also all the curl packages are properly installed on the server so its not that either.

Comment: Let me check it out.

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: @JoseRojas I did. I forgot how I did it